# Subset dataframe rows based on character vector when "%in%" and "which" are not working

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have stuck in this simple task of subsetting the rows of a dataframe based on a character vector:

```
# the vector:
vec <- c("8cc7e656.0152.4359.8566.0581c3",    
                   "b3696374.c6c0.49dd.833e.596e26_D2", 
                   "f635496c.0046.4ecd.89bc.7a4f33_D2", 
                   "e1cd3d70.132b.452f.ba10.026721_D2") 

# the dataframe
df <- data.frame(PCC=c("PNNL", "VU", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "VU", "PNNL"),
                     Participant.ID=c("01CO001", "01CO005", "01CO008", "01CO014", "01CO019", 
                                      "05CO002", "05CO003", "11CO051", "11CO052", "11CO053"),
                     Specimen.Label=c("5a3aa99d-ca10-45f6-939f-12392a_D2", "59891744-2db3-4541-a86a-7f911f_D2", 
                                      "8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3", "c9730cb4-b52c-4ca8-9652-4509d0_D2",
                                      "573048dd-2502-40e0-8e8c-c41bb8_D3", "f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2",
                                      "8fab37a4-cdf9-4ce8-9081-7b9148_D2", "b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2", 
                                      "0630ecb0-b664-4e75-bb3c-fb62ee_D2", "e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2"))
```

where I would like to obtain a dataframe containing only those rows defined by an exact matching between `df$Specimen.Label` and `vec`. Using the simple `df2 <- df[df$Specimen.Label %in% vec,]` returns a dataframe of 0 rows, while calling for the row indexes with `vec2 <- which(df$Specimen.Label %in% vec)` returns an empty vector of class integer.

However, grep returns the correct indexes. e.g. `grep("e1cd3d70.132b.452f.ba10.026721_D2", df$Specimen.Label)` returns `10`. So I thought why not replicating it like this:

```
ind <- vector("numeric")

for (i in (vec)){
  a <- vec[i]
  ind[i] <- as.numeric(grep(a, df$Specimen.Label))
  a <- NULL
}
```

but unfortunately this returns a vector `ind` (of length equal to `vec`) filled with `NA`s instead of the desired row indexes, along with a warning stating that "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". What is wrong here? Why grep works when called individually but fails to return values when used inside a loop? Thank you in advance for the fruitful solutions.

Comment: `grep` assumes `.` to be anything but `match` distinguish between `_` and `.`

Comment: The problem is that in `vec` you have dots, whereas in `df$Specimen.Label` you have hyphens, so your first commands do not return anything. `df[df$Specimen.Label %in% gsub("\\.", "-", vec),]` returns some rows of the original dataframe (with your sample data it returns rows 3, 6, 8, 10). Is this your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Just adding my comment as an answer since it was posted before the other ones)*

The problem is that in `vec` you have dots, whereas in `df$Specimen.Label` you have hyphens, so your first commands do not return anything. If you write instead

```
df[df$Specimen.Label %in% gsub("\\.", "-", vec),]
```

you obtain

```
#     PCC Participant.ID                    Specimen.Label
# 3  PNNL        01CO008    8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3
# 6  PNNL        05CO002 f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2
# 8  PNNL        11CO051 b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2
# 10 PNNL        11CO053 e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2
```

---

Another base R option is to use the function `subset`

```
subset(df, Specimen.Label %in% gsub("\\.", "-", vec))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is that `vec` contains dots instead of dashes. This code can tackle that:

```
#Replace
vec <- gsub('.','-',vec,fixed = T)
#Compare
df2 <- df[df$Specimen.Label %in% vec,]

    PCC Participant.ID                    Specimen.Label
3  PNNL        01CO008    8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3
6  PNNL        05CO002 f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2
8  PNNL        11CO051 b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2
10 PNNL        11CO053 e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2
```

Answer (score 1):

The string match fails because the data in `vec` is delimited by periods, but the data in `df` is delimited by dashes.

### Base R solution

If you replace the `.` with `-`, then you can use the `[` form of the extract operator with `%in%`:

```
# the vector:
vec <- c("8cc7e656.0152.4359.8566.0581c3",    
         "b3696374.c6c0.49dd.833e.596e26_D2", 
         "f635496c.0046.4ecd.89bc.7a4f33_D2", 
         "e1cd3d70.132b.452f.ba10.026721_D2") 

# the dataframe
df <- data.frame(PCC=c("PNNL", "VU", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "PNNL", "VU", "PNNL"),
                 Participant.ID=c("01CO001", "01CO005", "01CO008", "01CO014", "01CO019", 
                                  "05CO002", "05CO003", "11CO051", "11CO052", "11CO053"),
                 Specimen.Label=c("5a3aa99d-ca10-45f6-939f-12392a_D2", "59891744-2db3-4541-a86a-7f911f_D2", 
                                  "8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3", "c9730cb4-b52c-4ca8-9652-4509d0_D2",
                                  "573048dd-2502-40e0-8e8c-c41bb8_D3", "f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2",
                                  "8fab37a4-cdf9-4ce8-9081-7b9148_D2", "b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2", 
                                  "0630ecb0-b664-4e75-bb3c-fb62ee_D2", "e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2"))

vec <- gsub("\\.","\\-",vec)

df[df$Specimen.Label %in% vec,]
```

...and the output:

```
> df[df$Specimen.Label %in% vec,]
    PCC Participant.ID                    Specimen.Label
3  PNNL        01CO008    8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3
6  PNNL        05CO002 f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2
8  PNNL        11CO051 b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2
10 PNNL        11CO053 e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2
```

### dplyr solution

A solution with `dplyr::filter()` is as follows:

```
df %>% filter(Specimen.Label %in% vec)

   PCC Participant.ID                    Specimen.Label
1 PNNL        01CO008    8cc7e656-0152-4359-8566-0581c3
2 PNNL        05CO002 f635496c-0046-4ecd-89bc-7a4f33_D2
3 PNNL        11CO051 b3696374-c6c0-49dd-833e-596e26_D2
4 PNNL        11CO053 e1cd3d70-132b-452f-ba10-026721_D2
```